# Какую платежку подключить к tg боту aiogram?

Tags: python

Мне нужен сервис (онлайн касса) что бы прикрутить оплату через телеграм бота, желательно чтобы в этом сервисе была оплата картой, нужен сервис с готовой библиотекой для использования их api.

Comment: Вы сами уже что-то пробовали или ждёте сразу готовое решение ?

Comment: Пробовал много что, начиная с freekassa заканчивая всякими api с втб и не только втб

Comment: и что не получилось?)

Comment: нет, не получилось(

Comment: что конкретно? отправить пользователя в браузер на ссылку с параметрами оплаты или поймать хттп хук на сервере или сопоставить хук с заказом?

Comment: Какой сервис для этого выбрать ?